# What is the reason for the separate "print" call in the error handling in module 454?

Tags: tex-core

Here is the contents of module 454 (Scan for `fil` units; `goto attach_fraction` if found):

```
if scan_keyword ("fil") then
  begin
    cur_order ← fil;
    while scan_keyword ("l") do
      begin
        if cur_order = filll then
          begin
            print_err("Illegal unit of measure (");
            print("replaced by filll)");
            help1("I dddon´t go any higher than filll."); error;
          end
        else
          incr (cur_order);
      end;
    goto attach_fraction;
  end
```

When an erroneous additional `l` is detected, the program reports "Illegal unit of measure (replaced by filll)". Couldn't this be done simply by `print_err("Illegal unit of measure (replaced by filll)")`?

Comment: Just a guess.  The memory available at the time TeX was created was extremely limited, and repeated message strings are entered only once into the block of memory dedicated to that purpose.  `replaed by filll` is (probably) used only once, but the `Illegal unit ...` is ubiquitous.  Thus, it's a space-saving measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX's string handling is based around some limitations of 1970s computing (in particular, rather than letting some standard library handle allocations of strings, instead they're all kept in a statically allocated array which Knuth refers to as the string pool. See §50 for a note about this. The result is that the actual call in the generated Pascal code will not be, e.g., `print("replaced by filll)"` but actually `print(447)` (or whatever the actual string number is). The relevant code is in part 5 (§54–71).

As Barbara noted, `Illegal Unit of measure (` makes three appearances in tex.web (you can check in the index in the output from weave). This allows a savings of a few bytes which seems a silly optimization in our current era when memory is generally measured in gigabytes, but it wasn't uncommon for the total addressable memory of a multi-user system, even into the 80s, to be measured in a small number of megabytes. There's a reason that the original TeX had 16-bit addressing of memory.

Comment: Specifically, it saves 50 bytes (twice the length of `Illegal Unit of measure (`). I remember reading or hearing somewhere (probably in [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLABJEFgj0PWWQCiXDJ6UmR8BWQ6YcyVHv)) that TeX 82 needed around half a megabyte of memory (so about 500000 bytes) to run reasonably. So it saves about 0.01%

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Worth noting is that this isn’t the only such case of string-reuse in TeX. It was a fair amount more than 500K for a proper TeX executable. Lance Carnes and others managed to shoehorn TeX into a 640K PC running DOS, but I remember having a 32-bit executable on my first PC which was delivered with 1M of memory (I added later cheaper memory from a third-party supplier) and while TeX ran on it, it was around 15 minutes per *page* to run LaTeX in that little memory thanks to heavy disk swapping.

Comment: And I managed to get “This can't happen” when trying to compile a PiCTeX image on my Macintosh Plus with 1MiB of RAM and OzTeX, I guess around 1989.